# importing products with magmi

Tags: magento, magmi

I've tried to import some products with `Magmi`,after that,I couldn't find customer options that I've already had.
Even `sku,name,description,price,Size:drop_down:1
T-Shirt1,T-Shirt,A T-Shirt,5.00,Small:fixed:0:-SM|Medium:percent:2:-MED|Large:percent:3:-LRG
T-Shirt2,T-Shirt2,Another T-Shirt,6.00,XS:fixed:0:-XS:1|S:fixed:0:-S:2|M:fixed:1:-M:3`

Is there something I haven't done?
Should I click the plugins? Which one should I click?

And in my file(var/import),I have many csv files,but when I choose them and run.It will throw like 'csv not found'. What's the matter with it?

My `Magento` version is 1.4.1.1 , `Magmi` version is 0.7.17a.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the path that the file is reading the CSV. When you open the error look the path that's looking for the file and change the properties for having it correct.

Comment: It looks like nothing wrong about the path.And do you konw how to import the customer options?

Answer (score -1):

In the CSV base directory on the magmi UI, try changing `var/import` to `/var/import`